# conjugate function prove derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

If I know that $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$, $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$.
How do I prove that $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is differentiable at $\overline z_0$?

Comment: You mean $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z}))}$, right?

Comment: yeah thats what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $z \to z_0$ **iff** $\bar{z} \to \bar{z_0}$. In particular, the map $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is continuous.

Then note that $\lim_{z \to z_0} { f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_0}) \over \bar{z} - \bar{z_0} } = f'(\bar{z_0})$.

Finally, ${ g(z) -g(z_0) \over z - z_0} = \overline{\left( { f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_0}) \over \bar{z} - \bar{z_0} } \right) }$, and so we have
$g'(z_0) = \lim_{z \to z_0}  { g(z) -g(z_0) \over z - z_0} = \overline{
\left( \lim_{z \to z_0}{ f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_0}) \over \bar{z} - \bar{z_0} } \right)
}  = \overline{f'(\bar{z}_0)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then $f(\bar{z})=f(x-iy)=u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)\Rightarrow \overline{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$.Put $u_{1}(x,y)=u(x,-y)$ and $v_1(x,y)=-v(x,-y)$.

We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_1=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,-y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,-y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}v_1=-\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y)$. If $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,-y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}v(x,-y)$. So $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}$. Simlarly you can show $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}$. Actually this is biconditional since arrows are reversible. $f(z)$ is holomorphic iff $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: we only know that f satisfies Cauchy-Riemann in $Z_0$ only.so how this is true: ∂∂xu(x,−y)=∂∂yv(x,−y) ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable if the first partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ exist, are continuous, and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$

Since we know that $f$ is differentiable in $z_0$ we know that the above is true, and
$$g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y),$$
so the partial derivatives of $g$ are
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\;\;\frac{\partial u}{\partial(-y)},\;\;\frac{\partial(-v)}{\partial x},\;\;\text{and}\;\;\frac{\partial(-v)}{\partial(-y)}.$$
Evaluated in $\bar z_0=x_0-iy_0$ these become
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0),&
&&\frac{\partial u}{\partial(-y)}(-y_0)=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(y_0),\\[1em]
\frac{\partial(-v)}{\partial x}(x_0)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0),&
&&\frac{\partial(-v)}{\partial(-y)}(-y_0)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(y_0).
\end{aligned}$$
$f$ is differentiable, so these are all existing and continuous in $z_0$, and it is easy to see that they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Thus $g$ is differentiable in $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Therefore the function $g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $\bar z_0$.

By assumption there is a number $a\in{\mathbb C}$ such that
$$f(z_0+\zeta)=f(z_0)+ a\zeta +o(\zeta)\qquad(\zeta\to0)\ .$$

Using the definition of $g$ we therefore have
$$g(\bar z_0+\zeta)=\overline{f(z_0+\bar\zeta)}= \overline{f(z_0)}+\overline{a\bar\zeta}+\overline{o(\bar\zeta)}=\overline{f(z_0)}+\bar a\>\zeta+o(\zeta)\qquad(\zeta\to0)\ .$$
This shows that $g'(\bar z_0)=\bar a$.